# symlink points to correct binary, but still another is executed?

Tags: linux, python, symbolic-link

I'm a bit confused here on how this is possible. I installed a new version of Python, removed the old symlinks and replaced them with the new ones. For some reason though, the old binary still gets called?

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/bin$ python -V
Python 3.7.3
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/bin$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/bin$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Feb 19 17:37 /usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/local/bin/python3.9
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/bin$ /usr/local/bin/python -V
Python 3.9.9
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/bin$ readlink python
/usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

Anyone who can explain this behavior? Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: Just to make sure, try again with `command -v` instead of `which`. `command` is a shell built-in, `which` is not.

Comment: Thank you @DanielB ! `command -V python` gave me: `python is aliased to `python3'` which made me to believe it was an aliasing issue (I can't list aliases on RPi for example? don't know why). 
So I just resymlinked the python3 link again too, and now it works!
Feel free to turn this comment into an answer and I will accept it in 24h.

Comment: Bash? Try `hash -r`

Comment: [Why not use `which`? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/108618)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `command -v` instead of `which`. You can find more about the reasons behind this [in this Unix SE Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249). The short version: `which` is a non-standard tool of times long past. `command -v` is a shell builtin and a POSIX standard. On Bourne shells, you should use `type` or `command -v`.

As you have already discovered, aliases are one possible case that can only be detected with a shell builtin, for example:

```
$ alias
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
$ command -v ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
$ which ls
/bin/ls
```

In your case, it appears that `python` was aliased to `python3`. There’s lots of places where the alias could be defined.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed python once in one place.
Then you changed the symlink to another location.

I think that you have run into an optimization of bash for not
having to search $PATH every time you type a command,
by caching the results in memory.

The path hash is a hash-table, maintained by bash, that contains the locations
on disk where the shell should look for executable programs when a command is run.
The hash table gets cleared on events that obviously invalidate the results (such as modifying $PATH), or by using the inbuilt
[hash](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hash.1p.html)
command.

When you executed python again, bash just tried to get it from where it
found it the last time, which got you the old version.

To invalidate the hash for python, run one of the following
commands:

```
hash python
hash -r
```

Comment: Good answer, so upvoted. Because I think your answer is the most valuable in general. However, in my case the answer by Daniel B was what solved my problem, so I accepted his. 
Thanks nonethless!